# Append array of object in HTML on click next and previous button

Tags: javascript, html

I need to append object in two different `div` so I used array of object, each time click next button show the next object. The problem is that the next button did no work or make any action.

```
 var myArr = [
 {id: 0 , question1 : "Question1 Question1 Question1.", question2: "Question2 Question2 Question2"},
 {id: 1 , question1 : "Question1 Question1 Question1.", question2: "Question2 Question2 Question2"},
 {id: 2 , question1 : "Question1 Question1 Question1", question2: "Question2 Question2 Question2."}
 ];

var i = 0;
display(0); 

$('#prev__btn').click(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i--){
        if( i == myArr.length){
            i--;
            display(i);
        }
    }
});

$('#nxt__btn').click(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++){
        if( i == myArr.length){
            i++;
            display(i);
        }
    }
});

function display(i) {       

    $('#question1').empty();
    $('#question1').append(myArr[i].question1);
    $('#question2').empty();
    $('#question2').append(myArr[i].question2);

    if(i == 0) 
        $('#prev__btn').hide();
    else  
        $('#prev__btn').show();     

    if(i == myArr.length-1)
        $('#nxt__btn').hide();
    else
        $('#nxt__btn').show(); 
}
```

Comment: This -> `if( i == myArr.length)` will never be true, because the loop stops executing when `i` is no longer `< myArr.length`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
var myArr = [
  {id: 0 , question1 : "Question1-0 Question1-0 Question1-0.", question2: "Question2-0 Question2-0 Question2-0"},
  {id: 1 , question1 : "Question1-1 Question1-1 Question1-1.", question2: "Question2-1 Question2-1 Question2-1"},
  {id: 2 , question1 : "Question1-2 Question1-2 Question1-2", question2: "Question2-2 Question2-2 Question2-2."}
];

let move= n=> box.innerHTML = inj(item.innerHTML, myArr[(idx+=n+k)%k]);
let inj= (s,o)=> s.replace(/\${(.*?)}/g,(x,g)=>o[g]);
let idx= 0, k=myArr.length;
```

```html
<button onclick="move(-1)">Prev</button>
<button onclick="move(1)">Next</button>
<div id="box"></div>

<template id="item">
  <div>id: ${id}</div>
  <div>q1: ${question1}</div>
  <div>q2: ${question2}</div>
</template>
```